# Error falta " ;" en public static final int welcome Text=0x7f0700a3;

Tags: android

tengo un error en la clase R.java. Me dice que falta ";" en dicha clase.
Esto es muy poco usual. Quisiera saber como arreglarlo y porque pasa esto?
codigo  que da el error en R.java es el siguiente

```
public static final int welcome Text=0x7f0700a3;
```

Comment: Hosy MontoyaRivera, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**

Comment: Hola buen día ya si ya verificaste tu código fuente puedes probar hacer un "clean" y un "bluid" para volver a generar el archivo **R.java**

Comment: al realizar "Clean" y "Build" si existe un error en los recursos, el problema va a persistir, se debe buscar el problema en los recursos.

Answer (score 0):

Los espacios no están permitidos en identificadores.

```
public static final int welcomeText=0x7f0700a3;
```

El compilador espera

```
[modificadores] [tipo] [identificador] [opcional: asignación de valor];
```

Como después del identificador encuentra otro identificador, se confunde y pide el ";" que espera.

Answer (score -1):

Estas definiendo un `TextView` con un id "welcome Text", esto no es permitido:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome Text"
```

por esta razón obtienes un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debes cambiar el id del `TextView`, evitando espacios:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeText"
```

corrige lo anterior y sus referencias a este `TextView`, entonces construye nuevamente tu proyecto.

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.